# Intel compiler "runtime CPU dispatching" feature: Broken on non-SSE2 processor?

Tags: c++, c, icc, intel-composer

So we want to use Intel C compiler with *runtime CPU dispatching* enabled (this is on Windows platform). We use the options **/arch:IA32** plus **/QaxSSE2**, but *no* **/QxFoo** option. This should - to our understanding - produce a binary that runs on *any* IA32 (x86) processor, but still uses SSE2-optimized code path on processors that actually support SSE2 instruction set.

However, testing reveals that on the processor *without* SSE2 support (e.g. Pentium III) the binary will crash with "illegal instruction" exception! Interestingly, removing *only* **/QaxSSE2**, and leaving anything else as-is, produces a binary that works perfectly fine on the processor *without* SSE2 support.

Another interesting observation is: Using **/arch:IA32** plus **/QaxSSE2** *together with* **/Ob0** (disables inlining!) produces a binary that also works perfectly fine on the processor *without* SSE2 support.

At this point it would seem that either *runtime CPU dispatching* raises the CPU requirement of the "base" code path to SSE2, regardless of **/arch:IA32** option. Or that *function inlining* and *runtime CPU dispatching* don't go together. But we fail to find any mention of this in the Intel documentation. This is very important information, so we think this would need to be mentioned in the documentation!

Can anybody confirm the observation or clarify what's going on?

Thank you!

Comment: What you're describing *should* work just fine. Can you post sample code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Looks like a bug report to me, otherwise without any way to verify or proposal an alternative.  Even with code, who still has a functional Pentium 3 laying around?  Really rather best to tell Intel about it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It's a rather "big" project and cannot be made public. However, a small "hello world" program did **not** reproduce the problem. Guess the program needs a certain minimum "complexity" for _runtime CPU dispatching_ to actually have an effect.

Comment: "Even with code, who still has a functional Pentium 3 laying around?" - software developers have to, because some customers (more than you'd expect) definitely _do_ as well ;-)

Comment: So start with your big proprietary project, and start ripping code out until you get a minimal sample that reproduces the problem. It's tedious work, but that's how debugging goes. You should be able to get it down to something reasonably small, and certainly you can remove all sensitive information. I have several functional Pentium 3s laying around, as well as Pentium 4s and machines much older than that. Then again, I sort of collect these things!

Comment: Cody Gray, you are right, of course. But I hoped this "tedious work" can be avoided, because someone can confirm that _runtime CPU dispatching_ is **not** working with non-SSE2 processors, or that it requires _function inlining_ to be turned off. But it seems now this isn't the case. So the "tedious work" will be required, I guess...

Comment: I really think Intel compiler dispatching mechanism is broken. At least it doesn't perform as documented. Those issues are only getting worse when you try to be AMD compatible.